# Getting new file name after mv command with ebpf

Tags: ebpf, bpf

So I am testing out eBPF, and wrote some "hello world" program to detect file rename.

I am trying to retrieve an old and new file name with a hook on do_renameat2 function.

Below is my code:

```
SEC("kprobe/do_renameat2")
int probe_renameat2(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{
    struct data_t data = {};
    u64 uid = bpf_get_current_uid_gid() & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    data.pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
    data.uid = uid;
    data.op_code = 3;
    struct filename *from = (struct filename *)PT_REGS_PARM2_SYSCALL(ctx);
    struct filename *to = (struct filename *)PT_REGS_PARM4_SYSCALL(ctx);

    bpf_probe_read(&data.oldpath, sizeof(data.oldpath), BPF_CORE_READ(from, name));
    bpf_probe_read(&data.newpath, sizeof(data.newpath), BPF_CORE_READ(to, name));

    bpf_ringbuf_output(&ringbuf, &data, sizeof(data), BPF_RB_FORCE_WAKEUP);
    return 0;
}
```

However it seems the data I get in newpath and oldpath does not make anysense.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that `old_name` and `new_name` end up pointing at the same value? Or you're getting an error? Or `new_name` has gibberish? Or something else?

Comment: old_name gives me the expected old name of the file.
new_name gives nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake, do_renameat2 is not a syscall.

After fixing the way I get the parameters, the code works.

Changed this:

```
struct filename *from = (struct filename *)PT_REGS_PARM2_SYSCALL(ctx);
struct filename *to = (struct filename *)PT_REGS_PARM4_SYSCALL(ctx);
```

To This:

```
struct filename *from = (struct filename *)PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
struct filename *to = (struct filename *)PT_REGS_PARM4(ctx);
```